# Change padding between navigation menu and toolbar content

Tags: java, android, toolbar

How to change padding between hamburger home icon and `Toolbar` content?

There is padding even in layout.

Tried to place zero padding or change icon but it doesn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Padding is for layout you are using, Try this..

```
marginTop: 10dp;
```